# Fit iText 7 Table to Single Page with Images using JPype

Tags: java, python-3.x, itext, pdf-generation, jpype

I am attempting to fit all the content of a table to a single A4 PDF.

I found another SO article linked to the itextpdf page [here](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-resize-a-pdfptable-to-fit-the-page) on the same topic

However, I am not certain how it is supposed to be implemented. I have the above code converted to JPype and it seems to run. But I do not get the desired effect.

I want to be able to add images to this table, and have it size appropriately so that it maintains a single A4 page.

Source and example on my github page here:
https://github.com/krowvin/jpypeitext7example

[Example PDF](https://github.com/krowvin/jpypeitext7example/blob/main/original%20example.pdf)

[Source](https://github.com/krowvin/jpypeitext7example/blob/main/example.py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that this is the table to be fully fit into an A4 page:

```
    Table table = new Table(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(i + " Hello")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(i + " World")));
    }
```

Since it's too long to be fully fit via usual layout flow (e.g. `Document#add`), we should somehow scale it. But first of all, let us find how much space this table occupies if the page to be placed upon is boundless:

```
    LayoutResult result = table.createRendererSubTree().setParent(doc.getRenderer())
            .layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(1, new Rectangle(10000, 10000))));
    Rectangle occupiedRectangle = result.getOccupiedArea().getBBox();
```

Now let's create a form xobject of this table, which we will scale a few lines below:

```
    PdfFormXObject xObject = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(occupiedRectangle.getWidth(), occupiedRectangle.getHeight()));
    new Canvas(xObject, pdfDoc).add(table).close();
```

So now we have the xObject of the table, the only question is how to fit it, e.g. which scale coefficients to apply:

```
   double coefficient = Math.min(PageSize.A4.getWidth() / occupiedRectangle.getWidth(), 
            PageSize.A4.getHeight() / occupiedRectangle.getHeight());
```

We're almost done: now let's add the scaled version of the table to the document's page:

```
        new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.addNewPage())
            .saveState()
            .concatMatrix(coefficient, 0, 0, coefficient, 0, 0)
            .addXObject(xObject)
            .restoreState();
```

And that's it:
[image]

Comment: I added the changes you suggest to my Jpype (python) code and was able to generate the document. However the entire table is squished at the bottom. [see here](https://github.com/krowvin/jpypeitext7example/blob/main/example.pdf) Source [here](https://github.com/krowvin/jpypeitext7example/blob/main/uladzimir.example.py) Do you think this is related to how I am calling document/pdfDoc?

Comment: I got the squished table closer to what is expected by changing `Rectangle(10000, 10000)` to `Rectangle(600, 900)` I also tried `PageSize.A4` instead of Rectangle, but that cuts the bottom of the table off after row h

Comment: > However the entire table is squished at the bottom
This is expected, since by default the form x object is added to the (0, 0) position of the document. In my case the table was too long, hence it looked OK, but in your case the table is too wide, hence you see space at the top of the table.

This can be fixed: for example, you can consider the exact width and height the table will occupy on the table (by applying the coefficient on the occupiedRectangle) and then decide which arguments should be passed to addXObject as float x, float y (see the list of the method's overloads)

Comment: I applied the overload you suggested to `addXObjectAt()` (I'm using 7.2.2) and I'm real close! I have been tweaking the x, y values for Rectangle still as addXObjectAt()'s x/y seems to only effect the bottom left position of the table. I'm not 100% what you mean by using the occupiedRectangle Object? 

Would you mind tweaking your example to show what you mean please? I updated my code on github to show the current [pdf](https://github.com/krowvin/jpypeitext7example/blob/main/example.pdf) and [source](https://github.com/krowvin/jpypeitext7example/blob/main/uladzimir.example.py)

Comment: >  have been tweaking the x, y values for Rectangle still as addXObjectAt()'s x/y seems to only effect the bottom left position of the table. 

Yes, that's exactly what I meant. I mentioned occupiedArea, because you can take its heiggt and width into account while considering the exact x and y to be passed to addXObject

Comment: Okay great, sounds like i'm on the right track! I'll mark this answered. Thank you for your help